# Proxy pattern used by spring

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I am learning spring :)

I have following doubts,

1. Does spring creates proxy object for every bean even if I have not used annotations for example @Transactional which I think need proxy.
2. I read following in [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-getting-started-with-spring)

> Note that calls to static @Bean methods will never get intercepted by the container, not even within @Configuration classes (see above). This is due to technical limitations: CGLIB subclassing can only override non-static methods. As a consequence, a direct call to another @Bean method will have standard Java semantics, resulting in an independent instance being returned straight from the factory method itself.

a. Spring does not return proxy object in following example because of static method which is cannot override. So it will return original object here. Am I right?

```
   @Configuration
   public class Config {
       @Bean
       public static Student student() {
           return new Student();
       }
   }
```

b. What is meaning of "Note that calls to static @Bean methods will never get intercepted by the container, not even within @Configuration classes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a. Yes, you are correct. You will get the original object.

b. student() method is inside the class Config which is annotated with @Configuration annotation. All the methods which are annotated with @Bean inside @Configuration class are intercepted by spring by creating proxies. So as your method is static and though it is inside Config class, it will not be intercepted by Spring and no proxies will be created.

Comment: And answer for Q 1. is spring creates proxy for every bean and used jdk interface based proxy for that?

Comment: Yes, spring will create proxy for every bean if it's life cycle is controlled by spring. And spring will use JDK based proxies if your spring bean class is extending any of the interface. If it is not extending any interface, it will use  CGLIB based proxies.